# How to convert this list of lists of lists into data frame in R?

Tags: r, data-binding

Suppose we have something that looks like:

```
list of two months:

Jan
Feb
```

Then when you expand Jan and Feb, you see other lists (countries):

```
Jan -> USA, UK, etc.
Fab -> USA, UK, etc.
```

Finally, each country is a list, containing two items. E.g. opening USA in the Jan list:

```
USA -> gdp, population
```

What I'm trying to do is achieve a data frame like so (numbers would just be the values in data):

```
month country gdp    population
Jan   USA     number no.
Jan   UK      number no.
Feb   USA     number no.
Feb   UK      number no.
```

I tried `bind_rows(list)`, which doesn't quite work because the header becomes the countries and the columns are populated with numbers that no longer have their labels.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: `dput()` output:

```
list(`Jan` = list(UK = list(date_value = "Jan", 
    country_code = "UK", gdp = 308L, pop = 0L)
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear from your `dput` whether it is the same structure for the USA and others.   Can you test the code beloww

Comment: The structure is the same for each country it seems

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(lst2, bind_rows)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  date_value country_code   gdp   pop
#  <chr>      <chr>        <int> <int>
#1 Jan        UK             308     0
#2 Jan        UK             308     0
```

#### data

```
lst2 <- list(Jan = list(UK = list(date_value = "Jan", country_code = "UK", 
    gdp = 308L, pop = 0L)), Feb = list(UK = list(date_value = "Jan", 
    country_code = "UK", gdp = 308L, pop = 0L)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the following error: `Internal error in `vec_proxy_assign_opts()`: `proxy` of type `integer` incompatible with `value` proxy of type `NULL`.` Any ideas?

Comment: @HelpNeeded4 It may be that some elements are NULL in your original data.  I used `lst2 <- list(Jan = list(UK = list(date_value = "Jan", country_code = "UK", 
    gdp = 308L, pop = 0L)), Feb = list(UK = list(date_value = "Jan", 
    country_code = "UK", gdp = 308L, pop = 0L)))`

Comment: In that case is there a way to exclude NULL values, e.g. like `na.omit`?

Comment: @HelpNeeded4 if you can post the dput of a small example that shows the error, then it is ieasier to debug